# Get Maximum sequence for column value is number only

Tags: sql, oracle

SELECT * FROM TABLE;

```
CUSTNUM  SEQ    SECTION   
--------------------
220684     5    12c
213567     4    33
220684     3    25
213567     6    10
213567     2    a12
220684     1    30
```

Require oracle 10g query for output as mentioned below. Need to get the maximum sequence number for Customer number whose section column value is only number not having any digit.

```
  SQL> SELECT CUSTNUM,MAX(SEQ) FROM TABLE WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(SECTION, 
  '^[[:digit:]]+$') BETWEEN 22 AND 50;  ---  how to use between in regex

  CUSTNUM  SEQ    
  -------------------- 
  220684    3   
  213567    4
```

Comment: I've removed the SQL Server tag, as it is a different product, which often requires a different solution.  You could filter `Section` [to return numerics only](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php).

Comment: You say you need to check that `section` only contains numeric characters, so why the `between` in the query? What do you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test if the `SECTION` is a number in an inner query and then, having filtered out the non-numbers, you can filter the number range in the outer query:

```
SELECT CUSTNUM,
       MAX(SEQ)
FROM   (
  SELECT CUSTNUM,
         SEQ,
         SECTION
  FROM   TABLE
  WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE(SECTION, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
)
WHERE  TO_NUMBER( SECTION ) BETWEEN 22 AND 50
GROUP BY CUSTNUM;
```

If you try doing both filters in the same sub-query then it is possible that `TO_NUMBER()` will be evaluated before the `REGEXP_LIKE()` and the query will raise an exception for a non-numeric row.

Comment: ORA-12729: invalid character class in regular expression
12729. 00000 -  "invalid character class in regular expression"
*Cause:    An unknown character class was found in the regular expression.
*Action:   Ensure a valid characters class is being used.

Comment: @SanjeevAjay That regular expression works for me in Oracle 11g and it was the one you used in your question. You can also try the PERL style expression `'^\d+$'` but the Posix one should work